# Uber deliveries api returning 404

Tags: rest, api, integration, uber-api

I am integrating uber rush api and following the documentation https://developer.uber.com/docs/rush they recommend to use the sandbox url for testing. But all the urls are returning 404 page not found any one integrated the api please comment any change in the api.

Example url :https://sandbox-api.uber.com/v1/deliveries/15692cdf-55f0-4f11-9a0d-ad4954851574

Answer (score 1):

Uber RUSH API is not accepting any new integrations, and overall Uber RUSH is shutting down (https://www.theverge.com/2018/3/31/17184480/uber-uberrush-shut-down).   As you might notice, that URL you linked for documentation is hidden from the developer documentation. Thanks.